# How to align button in the middle of the body

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know I am doing it right but it is not being align properly. This is the **CSS** that I am using which means that every `<div>` button inside the body should be alight to the middle of the body. But it is not doing that.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: If it's not being aligned properly, you're not doing it right.  You asked this question 3 times already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I align this item with flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113597/how-do-i-align-this-item-with-flex)

Answer (score 2):

you must use this property for the button `display:block;`.

```css
html,body,#my-body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#my-body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background:red;
}
button{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div id="my-body">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `min-height:100vh;`

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height:100vh;
    margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div>Center</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `flex-direction: column` for this to work.